# Sqlite: Update multiple columns from a table

Tags: python, sqlite

**Issue**

I have imported a csv using python and created a table called upload. I want to update the Fixture table with the new upload table values. I don't want to insert as I have specific ids for each fixture and I dont want to mess it up with insert. Below is my code that works with insert but doesn't work with update. Any ideas?

**Sqlite code**

```
cursor = conn.execute("select * from upload")

for row in cursor:
    cur.execute("update Fixture \
                set home_score = ?\
                    ,away_score = ?\
                WHERE home_team in ?\
                and away_team in ?",(row[1],row[2],row[0],row[3]))
    conn.commit()
print "update fixture done";
```

**Fixture Table**

```
(1, u'2014-06-12', 1, u'Group A', u'Brazil', None, u'Croatia', 1, None, None, None, u'21:00 (ITV)')                                                                       
(2, u'2014-06-13', 11, u'Group A', u'Mexico', None, u'Cameroon', None, None, None, None, u'17:00 (ITV)')                                                                     
(3, u'2014-06-17', 5, u'Group A', u'Brazil', None, u'Mexico', None, None, None, None, u'20:00 (BBC)')                                                                        
(4, u'2014-06-18', 10, u'Group A', u'Cameroon', None, u'Croatia', None, None, None, None, u'23:00 (ITV)')                                                                    
(5, u'2014-06-23', 3, u'Group A', u'Cameroon', None, u'Brazil', None, None, None, None, u'21:00 (ITV)')                                                                      
(6, u'2014-06-23', 9, u'Group A', u'Croatia', None, u'Mexico', None, None, None, None, u'21:00 (ITV)')
```

**Update Data**

```
u'Cameroon', 1,4, u'Brazil'                                                                   
u'Croatia', 1,3, u'Mexico'
```

**Tests**

```
cursor = conn.execute("select * from upload")
for row in cursor:
    print row[1],row[2],row[0],row[3]
```

**Test Output**

```
2 1 Greece Ivory Coast                                                                                                                                                 
1 4 Japan Colombia                                                                                                                                                     
0 0 Costa Rica England                                                                                                                                                 
0 1 Italy Uruguay
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL, and it is unclear what the intended meaning is. Show example data and the desired results.

Comment: try commiting after all update has finished? just incase

Comment: you missed Fetchall() i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed `cursor.fetchall()`

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    stmt='''update Fixture set home_score = :home_score,away_score = :away_score WHERE home_team = :home_team and away_team =:away_team''' 
    cur.execute(stmt,dict(home_score =row[1],away_score=row[2],home_team=row[0],away_team =row[3]))
conn.commit()
print "update fixture done";
```

Comment: Sorry no change. There are no errors, I just don't see any change

Comment: Thanks for that but no change

Comment: It's Fixture but don't think that matters. Oh you have a spelling mistake above. fetchall() rather than fectchall()

Comment: I got no errors, so syntax is right...I think it must be something with the data..not sure

Comment: I have all the fixtures listed in Fixture table so I believe its update. I don't want a new row, thats what insert will do?

Comment: This works manually: cur.execute("update Fixture \
                set home_score = 2\
                    ,away_score = 1\
                WHERE home_team = 'Greece'\
                and away_team = 'Ivory Coast'")
conn.commit()

Comment: @Lorbat add unicode and try like home_team = u'Greece'

Comment: @Lorbat ur values are all unicoded use str(row[1]) and try

Comment: Yeah it works! I think the issue was cursor was created further up the code and it needed to be in the same batch of code as the for loop. Also your code above is definitely right which mine was wrong before